# How to model dependency between input features when building a classifier

Tags: python, classification, svm, data-science, feature-engineering

I have dataset with the shape of (1000,20) (1000 rows, 20 features) and I want to build a classifier for it.
However, most sk-learn algorithms assume the these 20 features are independent.
In my features, there is a gaussian dependency between the features.
How can I model this dependency as an input for a classifier like SVM or ExtraTreeClassifier?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a different Kernel than linear.

Since you mentioned there is a Gaussian dependency between your feature, I think Radial based function [RBF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel) kernel is the best fit for you.

Any of SVM libraries I know has this option for the kernel. For example, you can check the scikit-learn doc for the SVM [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC). Let's see the example that I took from that page:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC(gamma='auto')
clf.fit(X, y)
```

> SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
>       decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
>       max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
>       tol=0.001, verbose=False)

As you can see the kernel is set to **rbf** by default, so you can feel free to go and use it.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain what exactly is the influence of using RBF kernel?

Comment: Kernels are the way to measure the distance ( similarity) between pair of examples. When you use a linear kernel, you suppose the data is generated from a distribution where data are linearly related. But this case isn't always true.  So one major step before running a training pipeline is to understand the dependency between examples. You mentioned a Gaussian dependency between data examples. Gaussian is a special case of RBF, so using it, the distance you calculate between your examples are more meaningful. I added a link in my response, feel free to read it for more details.